# Robbery database biggest difference query with sqlite

Tags: database

I'm using sqlite.
Is it possible to get the information I need from my database with only one query? It works if I run 20 queries in a for loop (from 0 until 4000) , but it takes more than two hours to run :(
Can someone suggest a faster solution to get the same result?

I have a database (table robbery) that stores when and where a robbery happened. The robbery table has these attributes: date, city, id (PK). The date is the day when the robbery happened. 
I can't attach the real database, I don't have access to it at the moment, but it looks like this one:

[image]

I'm trying to get this information:
***The city with the biggest difference in the number of robberies for all months.***

For example from the attached database:
the city with the biggest difference in the number of robberies would be **Chicago**, because in July 2017 there were 4 and in May 2017 there was 1 robbery. The **difference is 3**. In the other cities this difference is much lower (1 and 0).

**I would like to get this result with a query:**
Chicago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_robbery (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                city TEXT,
                robbert_date DATE
);
```

My test data:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (1,'Chicago','2017-07-01');
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (2,'Chicago','2017-08-01');
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (3,'Chicago','2017-08-02');
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (4,'Chicago','2017-08-03');
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (5,'NY','2017-07-01');
INSERT INTO tbl_robbery VALUES (6,'NY','2017-08-01');
```

The query:

```
SELECT out.city,
   (select count(r2.id) from tbl_robbery r2 WHERE out.city=r2.city GROUP BY r2.city, strftime('%Y-%m',r2.robbert_date) ORDER BY count(r2.id) DESC) as maxcrime,
   (select count(r2.id) from tbl_robbery r2 WHERE out.city=r2.city GROUP BY r2.city,strftime('%Y-%m',r2.robbert_date) ORDER BY count(r2.id) ASC) as mincrime,
   (select count(r2.id) from tbl_robbery r2 WHERE out.city=r2.city GROUP BY r2.city,strftime('%Y-%m',r2.robbert_date) ORDER BY count(r2.id) DESC)-(select count(r2.id) from tbl_robbery r2 WHERE out.city=r2.city GROUP BY r2.city,r2.robbert_date ORDER BY count(r2.id) ASC) as crime_diff 
   FROM (select r.city FROM tbl_robbery r GROUP BY r.city) as out
   ORDER BY (maxcrime-mincrime) DESC
;
```

Query output:

```
city        maxcrime    mincrime    crime_diff
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Chicago     3           1           2         
NY          1           1           0
```

Answer (score 1):

(Using the same table schema and test data as Krzysztof's answer):

```
WITH total_robberies AS (SELECT city, count(robbert_date) AS robberies
                         FROM tbl_robbery
                         GROUP BY city, strftime('%Y-%m', robbert_date))
SELECT city, max(robberies) - min(robberies) AS variance
FROM total_robberies
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY variance DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

produces

```
city        variance  
----------  ----------
Chicago     2
```

One huge thing: In your sample data, you have dates like "1/07/2017", but you'll notice that he turned them into "2017-07-01". Using ISO-8601 formats means your dates can be used with sqlite3 [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Leaving the dates the way they are now would make things a **lot** more complicated. Don't do that.

Edit: Also, adding an index on the city column of the table will help a lot.